# Python: Debugging a function using Spyder

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am migrating from Matlab to Python with Spyder.

Let's assume I want to debug a function *fun* that outputs an error in line *l-error* and that this function is used in my code after quite some other scripts have run. In Matlab I would put a breakpoint *break* right where the function *fun* is called and then I will run this function from there by setting breakpoints inside *fun* before line *l-error* to understand what the error is about. I can get into the workspace of *fun* and let it crash since the code is still stopped in the script that calls *fun*, at the line that calls it (all the required inputs to call it are still available in the workspace). So I can run some lines of codes on the side to tweak some inputs of *fun* for instance, then call *fun* again until I find the issue. I can even modify *fun*, save it and call the newer version from the breakpoint *break*.

In Spyder, all is well initially: the debug mode stops at the line when *fun* is called, it gets into the function and stops at the eventual breakpoints I have there. But after I exit the workspace of *fun*, and want to call it again, it will run it but won't stop at the breakpoints set inside *fun* anymore. The only way I found is to re-launch debugging from the start. I think it may be related to the fact that the script actually imports the .py where *fun* is defined, such that it needs to be rerun from scratch everytime I modify *fun*.